# how to adjust the array index according to the contents of the variable that contains numbers

Tags: javascript

```
let ar = ['٠', '١', '٢', '٣', '٤', '٥', '٦', '٧', '٨', '٩']

let nm = 13
let result = ''

console.log(result)
```

how to customize nm variable with index of ar

ex: when nm = 1 so the result is index 1 of ar variable = ١

And nm = 13 , the result is combined index 1 and 3 of ar variable so the result ١٣

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would have to use a string for `nm` to allow for leading zeroes.

```js
let ar = ['٠', '١', '٢', '٣', '٤', '٥', '٦', '٧', '٨', '٩']
let nm = '0123456789'
let result = ''
for(let c of nm) {
  result += ar[parseInt(c)]
}
console.log(result)
```

```html
The output looks backwards but the language is just written right-to-left.
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your `nm` is number you can convert it to a string, split my letter, do lookup by letter, and combine back to string:

```js
let ar = ['٠', '١', '٢', '٣', '٤', '٥', '٦', '٧', '٨', '٩'];
//let ar = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j'];
[ 1, 13, 123 ].forEach(num => {
  let result = num.toString().split('').map(n => ar[n]).join('');
  console.log(result);
});
```

Output:

```
١
١٣
١٢٣
```